# Review of solved Pre-Calculus/Calculus questions (Range of subjects)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I really need some help. This has been driving me crazy for the past week! I've been working on this calculus sudoku and I cannot solve it, so I have come to the conclusion that I must have incorrectly answered at least one question. Are there any glaring mistakes here?
[image: Calculus Sudoku]

Thank you very much!

Comment: What's that box, fifth row, second column, say?

Comment: @KevinCarlson, that box says 2sin^2(theta)+2cos^2(theta), and my answer is 2. Is that the box you are referring two?

Comment: Sorry, I meant fourth row.

Comment: 7x^sin(pi), and my answer is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$7x^{\sin \pi}$ should be $7,$ rather than $1$.

Comment: Wow I feel silly now. Thank you very much!